# Problem Understanding OpenCV Convert Mat to BufferedImage

Tags: opencv, bufferedimage

I am a new user of JAVA OpenCV, and I am just learning through the official tutorial today about how to convert a `Mat` object to `BufferedImage`.

From the demo code, I can understand that the input image source is a Matrix form, and then `sourcePixels` seems going to be an array of bytes representation of the image, so we need to get the values from the `original` matrix to the `sourcePixels`. Here the `sourcePixels` has the length of the whole image bytes length (with size: w * h * channels), so it would take the whole image byte values at once.

Then it comes this which is not intuitive to me. The `System.arraycopy()` seems copying the values from the `sourcePixels` to the `targetPixels`, but what actaully returns is `image`. I can guess from the code that `targetPixels` has relationship with `image`, but I don't see how we copy values from `sourcePixels` to `targetPixels`, but it actually affects values of `image`?

Here's the demo code. Thanks!

```
private static BufferedImage matToBufferedImage(Mat original)
{
    BufferedImage image = null;
    int width = original.width(), height = original.height(), channels = original.channels();
    byte[] sourcePixels = new byte[width * height * channels];

    original.get(0, 0, sourcePixels);

    if (original.channels() > 1)
    {
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    }
    else
    {
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    }

    final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    System.arraycopy(sourcePixels, 0, targetPixels, 0, sourcePixels.length);

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `BufferedImage` is backed by a byte array just like the `Mat` class from OpenCV, the call to `((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();` returns this underlying byte array and assigns it to `targetPixels`, in other words, `targetPixels` points to this underlying byte array that the `BufferedImage`  `image` is currently wrapping around, so when you call `System.arraycopy` you are actually copying from the source byte array into the byte array of the `BufferedImage`, that's why the `image` is being returned, because at that point, the underlying byte array that `image` encapsulates contains the pixel data from `original`, it's like this smal example, where after making `b` points to a, modifications to `b` will also reflect in `a`, just like `tagetPixels`, because it points to the byte array `image` is encapsulating, copying from `sourcePixels` into `targetPixels` will also change the `image`

```
int[] a = new int[1];
int[] b = a;
// Because b references the same array that a does
// Modifying b will actually change the array a is pointing to
b[0] = 1;
System.out.println(a[0] == 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice and clear explanation! It makes sense to me now. I used to think Java doesn't have way to get address of the reference (like pointers variables in C++), and didn't not realize the "shared reference", like the one in your example, is still valid in Java. So in this case, can I interpret this line `((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()` as getting the address and size of `image` reference? In other words, it retrieves the address of `image` and makes the array `targetPixels` points to the same address as `image`'s?

Comment: @KatherineChen You can think of it that way, but to be precise, Java does not allow you to work directly with pointers like in C/C++, Java uses **references** to abstract away the concept of pointers, but essentially, a reference and a pointer represent a handle to a block of memory, it's just different in how low-level each language allows you to go

Comment: All clear out, thank you! It sounds like a level difference about how precise you can manipulate the address of the objects. TIL! thanks!